# insert in another database using tns

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, insert, tns

i am having trouble with my pl/sql code.
here is the issue :
when i try a normal insert using a tns(for remote database connection) everything works fine

```html
     insert into cell@DB2 (code) values(2);
```

but when i use the same insert in a loop in my pl sql code i get

> ORA-06512: à ligne 36
>   02069. 00000 -  "global_names parameter must be set to TRUE for this operation"
>   *Cause:    A remote mapping of the statement is required but cannot be achieved
>              because global_names should be set to TRUE for it to be achieved
>   *Action:   Issue alter session set global_names = true if possible

the problem is when i set the  global_names to true i get this error

> 2085. 00000 -  "database link %s connects to %s"
>         *Cause:    a database link connected to a database with a different name.
>                The connection is rejected.
>         *Action:   create a database link with the same name as the database it
>                connects to, or set global_names=false.

so it is either i can't use the tns and set the global_names to true or set the global_names to false and i can't insert using a loop

thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Is this real code you use?

From my point of view, here's how I do that: frequently I have to gather data from different databases and insert values into the *target* one, using a database link. One of values to be inserted are acquired via packaged function, so - if I try to do it this way:

```
begin
  insert into table@dblink (dp) values (pkg_ob.f_dp);
end;
```

I get the same error as you do. Therefore, I declare a local variable, put function value into it and insert a local variable:

```
declare
  l_dp number := pkg_ob.f_dp;
begin
  insert into table@dblink (dp) values (l_dp),
end;
```

Or, another option: if the above can't be done (because function value isn't "static" but depends on every row), I create a local table, insert values into it, and then - once everything is done - I "copy" local table's values into the one over a database link:

create table my_table (dp number, other_columns_here);

```
begin
  insert into my_table (dp, other_columns_here) 
    select pkg_ob.dp(some_id), other_columns_here
    from ...;

  insert into my_table@dblink select * from my_table;
end;
```